# Why do NSOutlineView cells overlap group cells when floatsGroupRows is Enabled

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, nsoutlineview

I'm creating a new app on Yosemite with an NSOutlineView created via the "Source List" item in the Object Library. By default, `floatsGroupRows` is enabled. I have top-level items as group items, and others as normal cell items. Which is great, except that, when I scroll up, the regular items don't disappear under the group items, but overlap with them:

[image: NSOutlineView Overlap]

Here I would expect the "Foo" item to be half invisible, but it's not, it's just flowing over (under?) the "THINGS" group item. Is there any way to fix this, other than disabling `floatsGroupRows`?

Comment: I think Apple is aware of an incompatibility between source lists and floating group rows. Certainly, floating group rows goes against the styling of source lists. The [10.7 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_7TableView) say, "In general, source lists should not float the group rows, and [outline setFloatsGroupRows:NO] should be called."

Comment: Ah, right you are. I switched from a source list to a regular outline view, and it works much better. Thanks. Happy to accept an answer if you care to add one, @KenThomases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Apple is aware of an incompatibility between source lists and floating group rows. Certainly, floating group rows goes against the styling of source lists. The [10.7 AppKit release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html#10_7TableView) say:

> In general, source lists should not float the group rows, and `[outline setFloatsGroupRows:NO]` should be called.

So, you should either not use a source list (i.e. use a normal style of outline view) or not use floating group rows.

Comment: Yep, a normal outline view does have more reasonable behavior for floating group rows. Thanks for the link to the very useful documentation.